# .sublime-build file type extension filter in sublime text 3

Tags: build, coffeescript, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I created file `/Users/maks/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/CoffeeScript.sublime-build` for automatic compile `coffee` to `js` when I press <kbd>super</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> on currently opened `.coffee` file:

```
{
    "cmd": ["coffee", "-c", "$file"],
    "selector" : "source.coffee",
    "path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

It works fine. But the problem is that it try to compile every file, on which I press <kbd>super B</kbd>, even if it is not `.coffee`. How to add filter and restrict it compile files which are not `*.coffee`.

So I want it to work as following: when I press <kbd>super B</kbd> on a file: if it is `coffee` file it should compile it to `js` else just save file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Tools > Build System and try enabling/disabling "Automatic"

Comment: the same result for me if this menu checked or not